# Starting activity from static method

Tags: android, android-intent, static, android-activity

I've a problem with starting Activity's. I'm trying to start a new activity whithin a static method.

This is my code for that:

```
    static Dialog dialog=null;
public static void NextLevel(Context c,String title,String message){


     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
     alertbox.setTitle(title);
     alertbox.setMessage(message);
     alertbox.setPositiveButton("Volgende level", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

         }
     });
     alertbox.setNegativeButton("Terug naar menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
             startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, MainMenu.class));
         } 
     });
     alertbox.show();
}
```

The startActivity doesn't work because it can't start an Activity from a static method. I just can't seem to figure out a way to solve this problem because I also can't create a context myself with which it could start it.

Comment: use as c.startActivity(new Intent(c, MainMenu.class));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
c.startActivity(new Intent(c, MainMenu.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

try change startActivity line to:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(c, MainMenu.class));
```

and parameter c to:

```
final Context c
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass instance of current activity into the static method and call **startActivity()** mehod on it.